# Get suggestion for line breaks based on text, font and available width

Tags: android

I have a text I want to manually draw and layout.
For this to look good, I would like to use a build-in method that suggests line breaks based on my text, the available width and the used font and font size.
iOS has `CTTypesetter.SuggestLineBreak` which does exactly what I need.

Is there something similar in Android?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you should use StaticLayout, all you need later is to call draw(Canvas) method

EDIT:

this a custom span that creates a real Button:

```
abstract class ButtonSpan extends ReplacementSpan implements OnClickListener {
    Button mButton;
    ViewGroup mParent;
    FrameLayout.LayoutParams mParams;

    public ButtonSpan(ViewGroup parent, String text) {
        mParent = parent;
        mButton = new Button(parent.getContext(), null, android.R.attr.buttonStyleSmall);
        mButton.setText(text);
        mButton.setOnClickListener(this);
        mParams = new FrameLayout.LayoutParams(0, 0, Gravity.NO_GRAVITY);
    }

    @Override
    public int getSize(Paint paint, CharSequence text, int start, int end, FontMetricsInt fm) {
        mButton.setTextSize(paint.getTextSize());
        mButton.measure(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        mParams.width = mButton.getMeasuredWidth();
        mParams.height = mButton.getMeasuredHeight();
//        if (fm != null) {
//            fm.top = fm.ascent = -button.getMeasuredHeight() / 2;
//            fm.bottom = fm.descent = button.getMeasuredHeight() / 2;
//        }
        return mButton.getMeasuredWidth();
    }

    @Override
    public void draw(Canvas canvas, CharSequence text, int start, int end, float x, int top, int y, int bottom, Paint paint) {
        mParams.setMargins((int) x, top, 0, 0);
        if (mButton.getParent() == null) {
            mParent.addView(mButton, mParams);
            AnimationSet set = new AnimationSet(true);
            Animation alpha = new AlphaAnimation(0, 1);
            int duration = 750;
            alpha.setDuration(duration);
            set.addAnimation(alpha);
            Animation scale = new ScaleAnimation(0, 1, 0, 1, mParams.width / 2, mParams.height / 2);
            scale.setDuration(duration);
            set.addAnimation(scale);
            mButton.startAnimation(set);
        }
    }
}

class MyButtonSpan extends ButtonSpan {
    public MyButtonSpan(ViewGroup parent, String text) {
        super(parent, text);
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        Log.d(TAG, "onClick [" + ((Button) v).getText() + "]");
    }
}
```

testing code:

```
ScrollView sv = new ScrollView(this);
setContentView(sv);

FrameLayout layout = new FrameLayout(this);
SpannableStringBuilder ssb = new SpannableStringBuilder();
ssb.append("Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. "
    + "Proin ac nisl nisl. Nullam [feugiat] sapien non libero semper suscipit. "
    + "Nulla nec convallis velit, vel [tincidunt] augue. \n\n"
    + "Integer urna sapien, [faucibus] a ipsum nec, blandit euismod lectus. "
    + "Cras eget tincidunt eros. Cras commodo [tempus] lorem, eu fringilla diam ultricies vel. "
    + "Donec massa ante, [consequat] sit amet orci non, rutrum interdum dolor. \n\n"
    + "Nullam gravida enim sit amet sapien bibendum, sed gravida nisl varius. "
    + "Sed hendrerit metus nec purus tempor faucibus. [Quisque] hendrerit vehicula urna sed interdum. "
    + "Proin imperdiet urna ac quam [euismod], vitae posuere metus pharetra. "
    + "Donec euismod lorem vel malesuada mollis. ");
int cnt = ssb.length();
int start = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < cnt; i++) {
    char c = ssb.charAt(i);
    if (c == '[') {
        start = i;
    } else
    if (c == ']') {
        int end = i + 1;
        Object span = new MyButtonSpan(layout, ssb.subSequence(start + 1, end - 1).toString());
        ssb.setSpan(span, start, end, Spanned.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
    }
}
TextView textView = new TextView(this);
textView.setTextSize(23);
textView.setTextColor(0xffeeeeee);
textView.setText(ssb);
layout.addView(textView);
sv.addView(layout);
```

Comment: I don't see how this would help me in knowing the exact bounds of my text lines. And that's what I need, because I need to embed other elements in the text.

Comment: so use Spannable.setSpan to embed other stuff and call Layout.draw to draw everything on the canvas

Comment: Can I use that to embed buttons in the text? If so, could you please show a short example?

Comment: if you mean button as android.widget.Button, then no, you cannot do that, but you can use ClickableSpans

Comment: Thanks. In that case, I am going to go with the way I originally planned.

Comment: and how are you going to handle Buttons? you would need to extend a ViewGroup

Comment: I don't see how this would be a problem?

Comment: ok so in this case you can use ReplacementSpan that gives you a chance to replace anything (even Buttons or any other Views)

Comment: @DanielHilgarth see my update how ReplacementSpan can be used

Comment: seems it was too complex, see simplified version

Comment: in onCreate for example

Comment: Hm, strange. I can't see the button. I can click it, but can't see it. Any ideas why?

Comment: hmm, have you set background drawable/color of TextView? tried hierarchyviewer?

Comment: Hm, when I first add the textView to the FrameLayout then the buttons are being displayed. In your version, first the buttons are added and finally the text view, which then is being displayed on top of the buttons.

Comment: yes it was my mistake: first TextView should be added then Buttons, so even if TextView has its background it doesnt hide Buttons

Answer (score 0):

It looks like [`Paint.breakText`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Paint.html#breakText%28java.lang.CharSequence,%20int,%20int,%20boolean,%20float,%20float%5b%5d%29) will do the job.