# How to insert a focusable/clickable ImageView at the end of multiline TextView?

Tags: android, layout, textview, imageview, imagebutton

I want to insert a clickable ImageView/ImageButton at the end of a multiline TextView, similarly to this example:

```
Text text text text text text text
text text text text text text text
text text text text text text text
text text text text text text text
text text text. | Image |
```

I was able to implement this using an ImageSpan and ClickableSpan that I added to the TextView, as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7913987/how-to-insert-imageview-at-the-end-of-multiline-textview) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5575438/how-to-add-click-action-for-the-imagespan/6357661#6357661). This works quite well, however, the ImageSpan doesn't support selector states, so it is impossible to provide the user with a visual feedback when the ImageSpan is focused or pressed (which is quite bad).

Does anybody know perhaps an alternative solution to implement this? Perhaps by using some custom layouts (like a FlowLayout that works with multiline TextViews)?

Thanks!

Comment: Why does it need to be inline with the text? Is this a requirement?

Comment: Yep, this is a requirement...

Comment: see my answer here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21933671/get-suggestion-for-line-breaks-based-on-text-font-and-available-width

Comment: Thanks! I quickly tested the testing code that you provided - it seems that it is exactly what I was looking for; also the selector on the buttons seems to be working...

Comment: and of course you need to replace Button with ImageButton

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just to close this question: I went for the custom span solution as suggested by [pskink](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2252830/pskink) in https://stackoverflow.com/a/21933957/441370. This worked perfectly fine. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

If You dont want click on that Image, Then you can use drawableRight property for EditText..

android:drawableRight="@drawable/icon"

If you want click then use below code.

```
<EditText
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:hint="Enter search key" />

<ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/button1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:src="@drawable/search"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:layout_margin="5dp"
    android:text="Button"/>
```